# How do I hide my dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am making a website using html, and now I want to make a dropdown menu wich animates down slowly. This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .nav {
    background-color: #25AAA0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}

    .nav_wrapper {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}
    .nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

    .nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

    .nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #66C3BC;
}

    .nav ul li a,visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px;
    display: block;
}

    .nav ul li a:hover {
    padding: 15px;

}
    .nav ul #dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    top: 0
}

    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="nav">
    <div class="nav_wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Vanilla</a><ul id="dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">Survival</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Creative</a></li>
                </ul></li><li>
            <a href="#">Modded</a></li><li>
            <a href="#">Servers</a></li><li>
            <a href="#">Help</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKCAJ.png) is what it looks like.
What needs to happen is that the black part is behind and not in front of the rest of the navigation menu, so I can slide it down using jQuery. Does anyone know how to do this? I already tried something with z-index, but that doesn't work. And please don't tell me how I can animate the sliding down, I'm not asking that, I'm asking how I can put the black stuff behind the rest of the navigation bar.

I hope you react soon.

Comment: This has nothing to do with php.. Please refer to the correct tags

Comment: It does because I used the include function in it so I could make a default navigation bar.

Answer (score 1):

```
.nav ul #dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    top: 50px;
}

.nav ul > li {position: relative;}
```

Be careful about `relative` and `absolute` positions.

You can animate it with CSS on `:hover` event or with javascript. I can help you with this if you wants but it's better for you to try first :)

You can hide it with several ways in CSS like `display:none;` `visibility:hidden;` or `opacity:0;` or `height:0;`

Here is a CSS solution I've made : [See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fepopubr/4/)

Comment: Thank you so much you have no idea how much you helped me but when I do it it animates it in but when I move my cursor out of the element it just disappears instead of going back nicely.

Comment: You're welcome ! Oh on what browser do you test it ? I have no problem like this on Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Never mind I fixed a lot myself like the dropdown menu showing up when hovering over the space underneath the li, look at this:

Comment: Sorry out of editing time, but take a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/beb7gydx/). Here everything is fixed. And that by a 14 year old! (Me!) I'm still working on it, so it'll be better soon.

Comment: Yep, it's working good :) It's another way to do it, with javascript. A little suggestion, you can add stop() function to your slide function to prevent a buggy effect when you hover multiple times too fast your dropdown menu. See this : https://jsfiddle.net/beb7gydx/1/

Comment: I have updated it, added a nice border, check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ksg7ppmv/1/) And I already saw that buggy effect, it was really funny actually, but kinda unprofessional so I'm happy that it's gone now, thanks